# Comparing default.value to this.value in a select box

Tags: jquery, html

I use this to capture any change on a existing html report (interactive)

```
    $("html").on("change","input[type='text'], input[type='date'], input[type='time']", function() {
        isDirty = (this.defaultValue !== this.value);
        if (isDirty)
            this.defaultValue = this.value;
    });
```

This checks for changes in any input type used in the report.

But how can you do something similar fore a select box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here - use [option defaultSelected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement):

```
$("html").on("change","select", function() {
    var opt = $("option:selected",this)
    var isDirty = !opt.get(0).defaultSelected;
});
```

Alternatively set an attribute onload:

```
$(function() {
  $("select").each(function() {
    $(this).data("defaultValue",this.value);
  });
});
```

and later

```
  isDirty = (this.type=="select")?
     $(this).data("defaultValue")!=this.value:this.defaultValue !== this.value;
```

Answer (score -1):

Getting the value of a select option is best done by:

```
this.defaultValue = $("select option:selected").text();
```

So your function will be:

```
$("html").on("change","option", function() {
    var value = $("select option:selected").text();
    isDirty = (this.defaultSelect !== value);
    if (isDirty)
        this.defaultSelect = value;
});
```

Comment: This will not work. Did you test it? You would need to set it onload if you want to do it like that

Comment: Why not mplungjan? He is not getting the value and with above code he does

Comment: He needs to see if the value has changed since the form was loaded

Comment: And the code I provided does just that. He just made one small mistake in getting the value.

Comment: There is no defaultValue on a select - so your first line needs to be in the onload of the page. Please see my answer for how to test if the original value has changed in a select

Comment: Also if there is more than one select on the page, `this.defaultValue`  set to the first value on the page with your code

Comment: OK, you are right with the defaultValue, just assumed that this was a global variable set somewhere else. I adapted my answer